# any chance to reject mp3 player application by apple?

Tags: iphone

I am planing to develop an iphone application that download mp3 files to  my application folder and play. Is there any chance to reject my application?

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely it will be rejected, since Apple includes the iTunes music player and your application would duplicate its functionality. The best people to ask, however, would be the folks at Apple.

Comment: Do you know how to get an answer from them on stuff like that?  It would seem like the logical thing to do, but sadly I've heard that they don't respond.  (Until you've submitted, that is).

Comment: Since Apple do not legally have a monopoly, they can do what they like in their space. From what I've heard, you'll definitely get rejected

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe the only way to find out if it will be accepted is to write the application and submit it...

Comment: Apple are an arbitrary and capricious god, whose will you submit to as an iPhone developer. They do not have to explain themselves to mere mortals such as yourself.

Comment: You could always go the ADC iPhone Dev forum and ask there. Lots of Apple devs over there answering questions.